# ios - Can we change Font, Size for all Label by single code / file?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I would like to ask, have any ways to change all Font, Size for Label by single code? 
Like Dynamic Type inside the app.
ex: Android have been supported with the XML file (dimens)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve that

1. You can do something like this to give the same styling for all `UILabel`s:

```
extension UILabel {
    @nonobjc
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
        //... here goes other changes
    }
}
```

You will need to use a convenience init every time.

2. Another option would be to create some custom `UILabel`:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
        //... here goes other changes
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
        //... here goes other changes
    }
}
```

3. The last option is relatively more complex and will require you to create customised way of handling different stylings for `UILabel`.